# matlab: color object tracking and position from video

Tags: matlab, object, position, tracking, color-tracking

i'm new using matlab and i started studying how detect an object from his color. What i'm trying to do it's to get the positions of my object (or my objects) detected and save them in  a file in order to plot them with the time of frames'acquisition. Indeed i need to find a way to have in the file also the time of frames' acquisition. 
I post the code:

```
 clear all 

a = imaqhwinfo;
[camera_name, camera_id, format] = getCameraInfo(a);


% Capture the video frames using the videoinput function
% You have to replace the resolution & your installed adaptor name.
vid = videoinput(camera_name, camera_id, format);

% Settiamo le proprietà dell'oggetto video
set(vid, 'FramesPerTrigger', Inf);
set(vid, 'ReturnedColorspace', 'rgb')
vid.FrameGrabInterval = 5;

% Iniziamo la presa dati del video
start(vid)


% Settiamo il numero di frame da acquisire (in questo caso si ferma dopo
 % 100 frames)
 while(vid.FramesAcquired<=200)

% Get the snapshot of the current frame
data = getsnapshot(vid);

%Per tracciare gli oggetti in tempo reale bisogna 
%sottrarre la componente rossa dall'immagine scalata dei grigi
diff_im = imsubtract(data(:,:,1), rgb2gray(data));

%Usiamo un median filter per filtrare via il rumore
diff_im = medfilt2(diff_im, [3 3]);

% Conversione dell'immagine nella scala dei grigi in binario
diff_im = im2bw(diff_im,0.18);


%Per migliorare ancora la presa dati eliminiamo tutti i pixel
%inferiori ad una certa soglia
% Remove all those pixels less than 300px
diff_im = bwareaopen(diff_im,300);

% Label all the connected components in the image.
bw = bwlabel(diff_im, 8);

% Here we do the image blob analysis.
% We get a set of properties for each labeled region.
stats = regionprops(bw, 'BoundingBox', 'Centroid');

% Display the image
imshow(data)

hold on

% Ciclo per chiudere gli oggetti rossi in un box rettangolare
 for object = 1:length(stats)
    bb = stats(object).BoundingBox;
    bc = stats(object).Centroid;
    rectangle('Position',bb,'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2)
    plot(bc(1),bc(2), '-m+')
    a=text(bc(1)+15,bc(2), strcat('X: ', num2str(round(bc(1))), '    Y: ', num2str(round(bc(2)))));
    set(a, 'FontName', 'Arial', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontSize', 12, 'Color', 'yellow');

    posizione_x = num2str(round(bc(1)));
    posizione_y = num2str(round(bc(2)));
 end

hold off

end
 % Chiusura dei due cicli.

 % Stoppiamo la presa dati
 stop(vid);

 % Flush all the image data stored in the memory buffer.
 flushdata(vid);

 % Ripuliamo tutte le variabili
 clear all
 sprintf('%s','Fine  tracking :) ')
```